# How do I obtain all the most recent elements from an IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I'm developing a Windows Forms application project for my university and we are using Entity Framework to store things.

It's an e-commerce type of program and now I'm struggling to find the right way to filter an IEnumerable based on the most recent ones.

What I want is to obtain all the elements from this table called [prices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2smK9.png), in which we also store older prices as a history backup.

This table has the ID of the article that refers to, the same for the corresponding prices list, a public, and a cost price, the updated date that is the moment it was created/updated.

I have tried using many expressions but ultimately failed miserably, sometimes I brought me only the ones within a certain price list or none at all or just one.

Again, I need it to work for a function that lets you update your prices based on parameters. For example, all articles and all price lists. For that, I want only the ones that are up to date so I won't touch the history of prices.

Example of what it should return:

[image: Example]

Thank you very much!

Update: What I have tried didn't work, in fact, I couldn't even find sense in the code I wrote, that's why I didn't post it in the first place. I guess this problem ended my brain and I can't think properly anymore.

I tried some answers that I found here. For example:

```cs
// This is an IEnumerable of the price DTO class, which has the same properties as the table. 
// It contains all the prices without a filter.
var prices= _priceService.Get();

// Attempt 1
var uptodatePrices= prices.GroupBy(x => x.ArticleId)
                          .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date).FirstOrDefault());

// Attempt 2
uptodatePrices = prices.Select(x => new PriceDto
                                        {
                                            Date = prices.Where(z=> z.Id == x.Id).Max(g=>g.Date)
                                        });
```

Comment: Can you update your question and show what you've tried? It all depends on how your database is setup.

Comment: Done. If there's anything else I can do, let me know please. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the rows in blue, but not the ones in white? I don't see a pattern with the blue ones. How do you know which ones are active?

Comment: The rows in blue. The pattern should be the date. 
For example, for article id 1 and price list 1 there are two items, only the one in blue is the most recent one. 
When I add a new price, this new price will be the price you want to sell the article, the original one will then be an older price (which we will later use for statistics and stuff). 
ALSO, since we are not actually working in lowering prices, just rising, another pattern could be that the public price will always be the highest.

Comment: It's certainly possible to do (it always is - I just don't know right now how you would), but if you can modify the database schema, you would get much better performance if you added a bit column that indicates whether the price is currently active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It sounds like you want to return the latest price for a combination of price list and article..

You're on the right path with your first attempt, but not quite there. The second attempt looks like pure frustration. :)

I believe the solution you will be looking for will be to group the products, then take the latest price for each group. To do that you need to use the values that identify your group as the group by expression, then sort the grouped results to take your desired one.

```
var uptodatePrices= prices.GroupBy(x => new { x.ArticloId, x.ListPrecioId} )
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(p => p.Date).First())
    .ToList();
```

When you do a GroupBy, the value(s) you specify in the groupby expression become the "Key" of the result. The result also contains an `IEnumerable` representing the items from the original expression set (prices) that fit that group.

This selects the Price entity, you can change the `Select` to select a DTO/ViewModel to return, populated by the price instead as well.

In your case you were grouping by just the ArticloId, so you'd get back the latest entry for that Article, but not the combination of article and list price.  In the above example I group by both article and list price, then tell it to `Select` from each group's set, take the latest Price record. I use `First` rather than `FirstOrDefault` as because I am grouping on combinations I know there will be at least 1 entry for each combination. (or else there would be no combination) Avoid using `...OrDefault` unless you're sure, and are handling that no result may come back.

Answer (score 0):

What you are working with are LINQ queries. If you only need to sort by most recent date, you can do that like this:

`prices.OrderByDescending(price=>price.FechaActualizacion).ToList();`

Make sure your Price model has the FechaActualizacion property.